# Ingress Controller External IP Address is Pending

Tags: kubernetes-helm

```
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace lonewolf-ingress --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="123.123.123.123"
```

IP is dummy here in the command

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.249.132   <pending>     80:31526/TCP,443:30368/TCP   24m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.0.149.158   <none>        443/TCP                      24m
```

IP resource is created successfuly by not associated with any thing what to use for React JS Front end App with internal routing to ASP.Net Core APIs I also have another confusion that my API's has whitelisted IP will it work when we run with this one IP associated with Frontend App and through ingress controller route to ASP.Net Core api.

Means I have one IP whitelisted and trying to use for frontend and from frontend API is called through internal cluster IP will it work or it will be denied.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question and StackOverflow is for programming questions only. Are you in the correct place? Or should this be in https://ServerFault.com?

Comment: Yes it is not a programming question it is a configuration question and I searched Stackoverflow and people ask this type of questions here and there are discussions about it